# Pulling wrong date from PDF, need 06/30/2023 date and the python script is pulling the left most date, 06/01/2023

Tags: python, pdf

I have been fighitng with this for some time. The python script below pulls the wrong date. The correct date I need is 06/30/2023 and the python script is pulling 06/01/2023. I tried various adjustments, and it's just not working. [PDF](https://www.mediafire.com/file/y35cxh1ackabc62/page_1.pdf/file) the code I have been fighting with is listed below.

```
`import os
import re
import pdfplumber

def extract_invoice_info(pdf_path):
    # Open the PDF file
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        # Get the first page (0-indexed)
        page = pdf.pages[0]

        
        # Extract text from the cropped area
        text = page.extract_text()
        
        # Use a regular expression to extract the invoice number
        # Adjust this pattern as needed.
        invoice_number_match = re.search(r'00(\d+)-IN', text)

        # Extract the date from the full page text
        text = page.extract_text()
        date_match = re.search(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}))', text)
        
        # Check if both pieces of information were found
        if invoice_number_match and date_match:
            invoice_number = invoice_number_match.group(1)
            month, day, year = date_match.groups()  # Extract date components
            
            # Create the new filename with the desired date format
            return f'{invoice_number} {month}-{day}-{year}.pdf'
        else:
            return None

# Specify the directory containing the PDF files
pdf_directory = r'C:\Users\gsawdy\Desktop\Results'  # Use a raw string

# Iterate over all PDF files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(pdf_directory):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdf_path = os.path.join(pdf_directory, filename)  # Use the current filename
        
        # Extract the new name based on invoice info
        new_name = extract_invoice_info(pdf_path)
        
        # Rename the file if new name was successfully extracted
        if new_name:
            new_path = os.path.join(pdf_directory, new_name)
            os.rename(pdf_path, new_path)
            print(f'Renamed {filename} to {new_name}')
        else:
            print(f'Could not extract info from {filename}')`
```

Comment: If a page has two (or more) matching dates, this code always gets the first one.  You would need to add code that checks if there is more than one date and then somehow decides which one is better.